# Usage of any with except

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Can I use plural nouns after any in the following sentences?

1- We don't have any options except to go there.

2- I don't have any friends except John.

3- I didn't meet any officers except him.

Comment: You can. The use of 'any' here is not really affected by the nouns, but by the clauses. Negative clauses (more technically *non-affirmative clauses*) like these normally take 'any'.

Answer (score 3):

For reasons which aren't immediately clear to me, I find plural ***options*** and singular ***friend*** in examples #1 and #2 respectively extremely "non-idiomatic".

I don't think it makes any difference whether the scope of ***any*** is subsequently modified by ***except X*** (or ***but X***, which is equivalent). Nor does it matter whether the initial negation uses ***not + any*** or plain ***no***. More extreme examples of "non-idiomatic" plurality might be...

> *I had no **choice** but to do as he said* [(153,000 hits in Google Books)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20had%20no%20choice%20but%20to%22)
>    ?*I had no **choices** but to do as he said* [(4 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20had%20no%20choices%20but%20to%22)

...which can be contrasted with...

> *I had no **friends** except (him)* ([664 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20had%20no%20friends%20except%22)
>    ?*I had no **friend** except (her)* [(10 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20had%20no%20friend%20except%22)

---

Turning to OP's example #3, I find both versions perfectly acceptable, but they seem to convey different nuances. Exactly what those differences might be isn't easy to pin down, but it might help to make a minor change to the verb...

> a) *I didn't see any **officers** except him*
>    b) *I didn't see any **officer** except him*

...where (a) seems more likely if I'd been interested in establishing *how many officers were present* (by ***seeing/identifying*** officers within a group, perhaps at a social occasion), whereas (b) implies a context where both conversants know I was intending to ***meet/interact with*** an officer (and I'm refuting the possibility that I might have met with *another* officer, as well as or instead of him).

---

But I don't see how the above distinction (which not all native speakers will necessarily agree with) helps in terms of formulating a "rule" here. Further enlightenment may come from comments.