# singular or plural nouns with "no" when "except" is used

Tags: grammar

Should I use singular countable nouns or plural countable nouns with **no** along with the word **except**?

- There **is no scientist** who is as renowned as Einstein except Stephen Hawking.
- There **are no scientists** who are as renowned as Einstein except Stephen Hawking.
- I have **no book** except this red one.
- I have **no books** except this red one.

I know it is more natural to use no with countable plural nouns in general. So we would generally say "There are no scientists in the hall." and "I don't have any books in my house." But when I use **no** with **except** the problem arises. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: I think this is essentially a duplicate of [Usage of any with except](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140568/usage-of-any-with-except), but I can't VTC against that one because nobody has upvoted the only answer there (mine! :) My answer does address the relevant issue - specifically contrasting the overwhelming preference for ***singular*** in *I had **no choice** but to do as he said*, as opposed to the preference for the ***plural*** in *I had **no friends** except (him).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "there is **no**..." then you are making a very definite rule. It is fine to use "except" only if you are making an exception to that rule.

In your first example of *scientists* - there are probably quite a few scientists that are renowned, or well known - Einstein, Newton, Hubble, to name a few that I know of and I do not work in the field of science. Still, if you intend to declare *one* scientist *the most* renowned, then speak in the singular:

> There is no scientist <s>who is</s> as renowned as Einstein except Stephen Hawkings.

If on the other hand, you wish to acknowledge that there is more than one renowned scientist then obviously use the plural:

> There are **few** scientists <s>who are</s> as renowned as Einstein, **but** Stephen Hawkings *is among them*.

You can see I haven't used "except" in this second example because I am not making an exception to any "rule". I have not said that Einstein is the *only* renowned scientist, and so Hawkings is not a single exception, he is simply joining the ranks of those renowned scientists I alluded to.

Also, you will notice I have scored out some unnecessary words - you don't need to say "are, are", or "is is".

In your second example about books, it is more a case of what question you are answering. If someone asked you "*which book**s** do you have*", then you would reply the same way, that you have "*no book**s** except this red one*". On the other hand, if they asked you "*do you have the green book?*" there is an assumption you only have one book, so you could answer "*I have no book except this red one*".